# What is the correct way to clear down an imported module for a unittest case?

Tags: python, python-import, python-unittest

I am unittesting a class Pigso in the module pigso.

```
class Pigso(object):

    _count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.__class__._count += 1
        self.ident = self.__class__._count
```

I set up a unittest with the intention of checking that the third Pigso object had self.ident == 3.

```
import unittest
import pigso


class TestPigID(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        reload(pigso)
        from pigso import Pigso
        self.pig1 = Pigso()
        self.pig2 = Pigso()
        self.pig3 = Pigso()

    def test_dummy(self):
        self.assertEqual(2 + 2, 4)

    def test_pig_ident(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.pig3.ident, 3,
                         msg="Pigso 'ident' {0} should be 'ident' 3"
                         .format(self.pig3.ident))
```

I have two questions:

1) What is the big picture on why this approach needs this 'triple pattern' of 'import', 'reload', and 'from module import'? (It was developed by guesswork based on error messages)

2) Is there a more elegant pythonic approach? It's my understanding that the unittest approach requires that the environment be completely cleaned down and rebuilt for each test case. If I'm correct that requires a method that restores imported units and classes to their state when they were first loaded into the test unit.

...later...

Following **TheoretiCAL's** response and much further research I'm coming to the view that the correct pythonic way is to delete the superclass object† either explicitly or implicitly in the fixture's teardown. 
If it is implicit then unittest needs modifying. If it is explicit then I need to add a tearDown method with `Pigso.destroy.__superclass__()`. As far as I am aware that function is not yet available in Python. 

I do think that organizing the deletion of the superclass object in the unittest import section and fixture setUp is neither pythonic nor compliant with core design concepts for unit testing.

I'll be interested to hear others' observations on this particularly with ideas on how to implement `Pigso.destroy.__superclass__`.

*†My understanding of 'superclass object' is that is the place where `_count` resides.*

Answer (score 0):

1. The big picture is that all unit tests should run independent of each other, which is why you have a set up function that is called before every test case is run. You have reload in the setup because without it, if the state of the module changed your tests would no longer be independent. Your from statement to retrieve your objects are unavoidable.
2. Based on the tests you provided if you are only checking indentation, you can remove test_dummy, ensuring only 1 test case, so you can remove the import and reload statement.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful reply. 
`test_dummy` is necessary for this example code which was reduced to the minimum necessary for others to test or play with. The `test_dummy()` function has a side effect because of the way unittest operates. If the Pigso superclass object is not correctly deleted then six Pigso objects will be created before `pig3.ident` gets tested in `test_pig_ident` and `self.pig3.ident == 6` so the test fails.

Comment: You could put the reload in the teardown method .... Or just set the class count variable to zero

Comment: Relocating both the import module and reload(module) statements to a tearDown method does work. It's also helpful for anyone reading the code becuse it links the statements to the tear down process.
I'm not comfortable with resetting individual class attributes in the tearDown method. For example: If test Fixture A clears down its own class attributes but has side effects that alter the class attributes used in Test Fixture B then B cannot operate with the isolation required for unittesting.